# Codeigniter3 / Mysql - Select List

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Bom dia Pessoal.

Estou trabalhando em um código usando Codeigniter, no qual tem um formulário de cadastro. Este formulário tem três Dropdown (Estado, Cidade e Bairro), sendo que os dados são retornados do banco, de acordo com a seleção, ou seja, se eu selecionar o estado do RJ, aparece somente cidades do RJ....

Consegui fazer funcionar na página de cadastro, mas não consegui na página em que consulto os dados de um cadastro já feito, onde deveria vir tudo preenchido conforme cadastro realizado anteriormente. Na página de consulta, o UF aparece preenchido corretamente, mas CIDADE e BAIRRO aparecem a opção padrão (SELECIONE) e com disabled ativado.

RESUMO:

Qual a melhor forma de realizar este código de forma que fique fácil de re-utilizar?

Como mostrar o Dropdown já com a informação selecionada?

Segue meu código:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var base_url = "<?php echo base_url() ?>";

$(function () {

    var codigo_cliente = $('#cCodigocliente').val();
    var uf = $('#cUf').val();


    $.post(base_url + 'ajax/cidades/search_cidades', {
        codigo_cliente: codigo_cliente,
        uf: uf
    }, function (data) {
        $('#cCidade').html(data);
        if (uf !== '') {
            $('#cCidade').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });

    $('#cUf').change(function () {

        $('#cCidade').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#cCidade').html("<option>Selecione</option>");
        $('#cBairro').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#cBairro').html("<option>Selecione</option>");

        var uf = $('#cUf').val();

        $.post(base_url + 'ajax/cidades/search_cidades', {
            uf: uf
        }, function (data) {
            $('#cCidade').html(data);

            if (uf !== '') {
                $('#cCidade').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });

    });

    $('#cCidade').change(function () {

        var codigo_cidade = $('#cCidade').val();

        $.post(base_url + 'ajax/bairros/search_bairros', {
            codigo_cidade: codigo_cidade
        }, function (data) {
            $('#cBairro').html(data);
            if (codigo_cidade !== '') {
                $('#cBairro').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

**VIEW**

```
<label for="">UF</label>
<?php echo form_dropdown('cUf', $ufs_item, $cliente_item['uf'], 'id="cUf" 
   class="form-control input cUf"');
?>

<label for="">CIDADE</label>
<select style="text-transform:uppercase" name="cCidade" id="cCidade" class="form-control input cCidade" disabled>                                                            
   <option value="">Selecione</option>
</select>

<label for="">BAIRRO</label>
<select style="text-transform:uppercase" name="cBairro" id="cBairro" class="form-control input cBairro" disabled><option>Selecione</option>
</select>
```

**CONTROLLER-CLIENTES**

```
public function listar_cliente($codigo_cliente) {
    //SOLICITA OS DADOS DO CLIENTE QUE ESTÁ SENDO CONSULTADO
    $data['cliente_item'] = $this->clientes_model->get_cliente($codigo_cliente);

    if (empty($data['cliente_item'])) {
        show_404();
    } else {;
        $this->load->model("ufs_model");

        //SOLICITA TODOS OS ESTADOS
        $data['ufs_item'] = $this->ufs_model->get_Ufs();

        $this->load->view('inc/header_view');
        $this->load->view('clientes/listar_cliente', $data);
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER-CIDADE**

```
public function search_cidades(){
    //RECEBE POST(AJAS) PÁGINA EDITA CLIENTES
    $codigo_cliente = $this->input->post('codigo_cliente');
    $uf = $this->input->post('uf');

    //VERIFICA SE O CODIGO DO CLIENTES ESTÁ VAZIO
    //VAZIO = CADASTRO NOVO   |   VALOR = EDITAR CADASTRO
    if(is_null($codigo_cliente)){
        //SOLICITA TODAS AS CIDADES DA UF VIA POST
        $cidades_item = $this->localizacao_model->get_Cidades($uf);
        //RETORNO FUNÇÃO CODEIGNITER QUE CRIA DROPDOWN CIDADE, SEM NENHUM OPTION SELECIONADO
        echo form_dropdown('cCidade', $cidades_item, '', 'id="cCidade" class="form-control input cCidades"');
    }else{
        //SOLICITA A CIDADE DO CLIENTE ATRAVÉS DO CODIGO_CLIENTE VIA POST
        $cidade_item = $this->localizacao_model->get_CidadeByCliente($codigo_cliente);
        //SOLICITA TODAS AS CIDADES DA UF VIA POST
        $cidades_item = $this->localizacao_model->get_Cidades($uf);
        //RETORNO FUNÇÃO CODEIGNITER QUE CRIA DROPDOWN CIDADE, COM OPTION SELECIONADO($cidade_item)
        echo form_dropdown('cCidade', $cidades_item, $cidade_item['cidade'], 'id="cCidade" class="form-control input cCidade"');  

    }

}
```

**CONTROLLER-BAIRRO**

```
public function search_bairros(){
    //RECEBE POST(AJAS) PÁGINA EDITA CLIENTES
    $codigo_cliente = $this->input->post('codigo_cliente');
    $ccodigo_cidade = $this->input->post('codigo_cidade');

    //VERIFICA SE O CODIGO DO CLIENTES ESTÁ VAZIO
    //VAZIO = CADASTRO NOVO   |   VALOR = EDITAR CADASTRO
    if(is_null($codigo_cliente)){
        //SOLICITA TODAS OS BAIRROS DA CIDADE VIA POST
        $bairros_item = $this->cidades_model->get_Bairros($codigo_cidade);
        //RETORNO FUNÇÃO CODEIGNITER QUE CRIA DROPDOWN BAIRRO, SEM NENHUM OPTION SELECIONADO
        echo form_dropdown('cBairro', $bairros_item, '', 'id="cBairro" class="form-control input cBairro"');
    }else{
        //SOLICITA O BAIRRO DO CLIENTE ATRAVÉS DO CODIGO_CLIENTE VIA POST
        $bairro_item = $this->bairros_model->get_BairroByCliente($codigo_cliente);
        //SOLICITA TODAS OS BAIRROS DA CIDADE VIA POST
        $bairros_item = $this->bairros_model->get_Bairros($codigo_cidade);
        //RETORNO FUNÇÃO CODEIGNITER QUE CRIA DROPDOWN BAIRRO, COM OPTION SELECIONADO($bairro_item)
        echo form_dropdown('cBairro', $bairros_item, $bairro_item['bairro'], 'id="cBairro" class="form-control input cBairro"');
    }

}
```

**MODEL-UFS**

```
public function get_Ufs() {
    $query = $this->db
            ->order_by('uf')
            ->get('tb_conf_ufs')->result();

    $list = array();
    $list[''] = "SELECIONE";
    foreach ($query as $result) 
    {
        $list[$result->uf] = $result->uf;                
    }
    return $list;   
}
```

**MODEL-CIDADES**

```
//RETORNA TODAS CIDADES DE ACORDO COM O ESTADO INFORMADO
public function get_Cidades($uf = null) {
    $query = $this->db
            ->where("uf", $uf)
            ->order_by('cidade')
            ->get('tb_conf_cidades')->result();

    $list = array();
    $list[''] = "SELECIONE";
    foreach ($query as $result) 
    {
        $list[$result->codigo_cidade] = $result->cidade;                
    }
    return $list;   
}

//RETORNA A CIDADE DO CLIENTE CONSULTADO
public function get_CidadeByCliente($codigo_cliente) {
    $codigo = $codigo_cliente;
    $query = $this->db
            ->select('cidade')
            ->where('codigo_cliente', $codigo)
            ->get('tb_clientes');

    return $query->row_array();
}
```

**MODEL-BAIRROS**

```
//RETORNA OS BAIRROS DE ACORDO COM A CIDADE INFORMADA
public function get_Bairros($codigo_cidade = null) {
    $query = $this->db
            ->where("codigo_cidade", $codigo_cidade)
            ->order_by('bairro')
            ->get('tb_conf_bairros')->result();

    $list = array();
    $list[''] = "SELECIONE";
    foreach ($query as $result) 
    {
        $list[$result->codigo_cidade] = $result->cidade;                
    }
    return $list;   
}

//RETORNA O BAIRRO DO CLIENTE CONSULTADO
public function get_BairroByCliente($codigo_cliente) {
    $codigo = $codigo_cliente;
    $query = $this->db
            ->select('codigo_bairro')
            ->where('codigo_cliente', $codigo)
            ->get('tb_clientes');

    return $query->row_array();
}
```

**Alguem poderia ajudar pessoal?
    Quero criar 3 Dropdowns dependentes (UF>CIDADE>BAIRRO), na pagína de consulta de cliente já cadastrado, ou seja, com as informações já preenchidas.**

Comment: Quando vc diz "re-utilizar" está falando de _CRUD_? Ou seja, está falando de usar o mesmo `form` pra cadastrar e pra preencher com dados que já estão cadastrados (editar)? É isso?

Comment: Sim, vi vários exemplos de como criar um SELECT DINAMICO, mas apenas de dois campos e para o form de cadastro novo. Consegui fazer o de cadastro novo com três campos, mas quando tento fazer para um form de consulta do cliente cadastrado, me deparo com a situação onde tenho que fazer tudo de novo, pois nele vou precisar mostrar o option selecionado.

Comment: Você pode fazer uma verificação, veja se o metodo é para adicionar ou editar, se for editar, você faz a busca de acordo com o banco de dados. :)

Comment: Atualizei o código de acordo com minhas tentativas, mesma assim nao deu certo o SELECT

UF>CIDADE>BAIRRO

Tanto para cadastro novo ou consulta cadsatro.

Comment: Ola, espero que vc esteja bem e tenha encontrado a resposta...
caso não, veja estes links http://snehakinkar.blogspot.com/2013/05/cascading-list-of-country-state-city.html http://www.91weblessons.com/codeigniter-ajax-country-state-city-drop-down/ https://github.com/eboominathan/Dependent-Dropdown-in-Codeigniter-3.0.3 http://makitweb.com/dynamic-dependent-dropdown-in-codeigniter-with-ajax/